# ¿Cómo hacer un mapa con claves múltiples en Go?

Tags: go

Estoy iterando sobre muchos datos y necesito organizarlos en algún tipo de mapa multidimensional.

Los datos que necesito guardar en este proceso son: `companyid`,`mes`,`montoTotal`. Lo importante es que estos valores los pueda guardar en cada iteración, para que cuando venga otro valor con el mismo `companyId` y el mismo `mes` pueda tomar el que ya tiene seteado y sumar el nuevo.

He probado con `struct` pero no me sirve, ya que una vez agregado el elemento no puedo acceder a los valores por medio del `companyId` y `mes` como lo haría en php: `(variable[companyId][mes] = variable[companyId][mes] + nuevoValor)`

En este momento tengo esto, pero la llave del map solo soporta 1 registro:

```
var masterMatriz = map[string]map[string]string{}

for _, value := range *mysqlResult{

 date := explode("-", value.Adj_date)
 dateKey := date[0] + "-" + date[1]

 if val, exist := masterMatriz[value.Company_id][dateKey]; !exist {
   masterMatriz[value.Company_id] = map[string]string{
                        dateKey: totalInLocalCurrency_formated,
                    }
 }else{
     current := masterMatriz[value.Company_id][dateKey]
     masterMatriz[value.Company_id][dateKey] = current + totalInLocalCurrency_formated

}

}
```

El problema de mi código es que al ser `string` mi llave siempre guardará 1 fecha por cada llave de `companyId`.

Answer (score 0):

no estoy seguro si entendí tu pregunta.

Creo que lo que querés se puede solucionar con un struct el cual va a tener structs asosciados.

```
package main

type company struct {
    name       string
    otherValue string
    dates      map[string]date
}

type date struct {
    date    string
    value      float64
    otherValue string
}

func main() {

    masterMatriz := make(map[string]company)
    dates := make(map[string]date)
    1234 := date{"1234", 111.0, "bla"}
    date["1234"] = 1234
    google := company{"google", "bla", dates}
    masterMatriz["google"] = google
    
    
    for _, value := range *mysqlResult {

        date := explode("-", value.Adj_date)
        dateKey := date[0] + "-" + date[1]
        
        company := masterMatriz[value.Company_id]
        
        if len(company) == 0 {
            masterMatriz[value.Company_id] = createNewCompany(value)
        }
        
        date := company[dateKey]
        
        if len(date) == 0 {
            company[dateKey] = createNewDate(value)
        }
        
        date.value = date.value + newValue

    }
}
```

Evidentemente vas a tener que crear los métodos createNewCompany y createNewDate pero incluí algunas lineas de ejemplo en el main para que veas como se inicializan estos structs.

Espero te sirva, saludos!